# Dense layer dimension error even after using flatten

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, mnist

I'm new to Keras and using the following model to experiment with the MNIST problem.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
             padding='same', activation='relu',
             bias_initializer='RandomNormal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same',    
          activation='relu', bias_initializer='RandomNormal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I get this error even though I'm adding a flatten layer:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2     
dimensions, but got array with shape (4200, 28, 28, 10)
```

If things work for the first dense layer, why is there a problem with the second (softmax) layer?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: But after 2 MaxPooling2D calls and a flatten call, the input dimension to the dense_1 layer should be x_dim * y_dim * num filters = 7*7*32 = 1568.  This works just fine when I code it directly in Tensorflow.

Comment: Sorry for the false alarm.  I found an error in the order of the parameters I was passing into the fit method.  I wish the error would have pointed me there in the first place,